# Add for loop based on conditional

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a function which return two kind of array as below

// first array

```
$arr = array(
    'P' => array(
        'val1' => 1,
        'val2' => 12
    ),
    'T' => array(
        'val1' => 4,
        'val2' => 5
    )
);
```

// second array

```
$arr = array(
    'South' => array(
            'P' => array(
                'val1' => 1,
                'val2' => 12
            ),
            'T' => array(
                'va11' => 14,
                'val2' => 15
            ),
    ),
    'North' => array(
            'P' => array(
                'val1' => 6,
                'val2' => 9
            ),
            'T' => array(
                'va11' => 23,
                'val2' => 22
            )
    )
);
```

The second arr has a index more than the first array, which i want to loop and display

// my code

```
$arrStr = 'first';
if ($flag == 1)
    $arrStr = 'second';
if ($flag == 1)
    for ($retarr =>$directionIndex => $retArr) {
        for (${$arrStr} as $ky=>$valArr) {
            // so i have to close the for loop also based on condition , which does not work ,
        } // end of first for 
        if ($flag == 1)
    }  // end of second for
```

Is there a  better way to loop on condition , or should i correct the function and split the whole display thing duplicated twice based on flag

Comment: why you no use braces!!!

Comment: You can always break the for loop(s) in case you match the conditions: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: @Pogrindis braces for the if conditional , would interfere with the braces i want to add

Comment: this is flaky.. why not use a switch statement or something ? You're making the same check 3x ... Better yet, create a function ?